# Difference btw Fiware GEris and GEi?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan

I studied through many websites about Fiware GEris and GEi ,but was not able to properly understand about them and their difference ??

One of them was : https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE_Frequently_Asked_Questions_(FAQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained at https://ask.fiware.org/question/1/what-is-a-fiware-ge-and-a-gei/:

> A GE (whics stands for "Generic Enabler") is a sofware component definition based on an open specification. For example, the Publish/Subscribe Context Broker (sometimes referred as Context Broker for short) is one of the FIWARE GEs.
>
> A GEi (which stands for "GE implementation) is a a particular implementation of a given GE. For example, Orion Context Broker is a GEi of the Publish/Subscribe Context Broker GE. A given GE may have several GEi (some of them even developed by third-parties outside FIWARE, given that the specifications in which a GE is based are open).
>
> There is a third key term: GEri (which stands for "GE reference implementation"). A GEri is a particular GEi of a given GE which is provided by FIWARE as a reference implementation of that GE. For example, it happens to be that Orion Context Broker is not only a GEi for Publish/Subscribe Context Broker GE, but also a GEri for that GE.